# Is it possible to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{4ix}}{1+x^4} dx$ as itself and if so by what contour?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible to evaluate 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{4ix}}{1+x^4} dx
$$ 
without breaking the exponential part to the sine and cosine parts and if so by what contour?

It fails

[So far, I've made an attempt by using contour $[0,2R] \cup \gamma_R$ with positive orientation where $\gamma_R (t) = Re^{it} +R$.

Few calculations on the controlling part of the integral over the arc:
$$
\int_{\gamma_R} f(z) dz = i \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp \left( 4i \{ Re^{it} + R \} \right)}{1+ (Re^{it} + R)^4}Re^{it} dt,
$$
and by some calculations, we yield
$$
\left| i \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp \left( 4i \{ Re^{it} + R \} \right)}{1+ (Re^{it} + R)^4}Re^{it} dt \right|
\leq 
R \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp \left( -4R \sin t \right)}{\left| 1+ (Re^{it} + R)^4 \right| }  dt.
$$
And since
$$
\left| 1+ (Re^{it} + R)^4 \right| \geq 1,
$$
we get 
$$
R \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\exp \left( -4R \sin t \right)}{\left| 1+ (Re^{it} + R)^4 \right| }  dt
\leq 
R  \int_{0}^{\pi} \exp \left( -4R \sin t \right)  dt.
$$
And by choosing $\delta > 0$ sufficiently small, on $ \delta \leq t \leq \pi - \delta$, we get 
$$
\exp \left( -4R \sin t \right) \leq \exp \left( -4R \sin \delta \right).
$$
Thus
$$
R  \int_{0}^{\pi} \exp \left( -4R \sin t \right)  dt
\leq
R \left( 2\delta + \frac{R}{\exp(R \sin \delta)}  (\pi - 2\delta) \right)
$$
]

Comment: Can you find all the complex solutions of $z^4+1=0$?

Comment: @Avitus Yes....

Comment: How did you get that the integral over $\gamma_R$ vanishes (in the limit for $R \to \infty$, presumably)? I don't think it does.

Comment: Yes definitely $R \to \infty$. I didn't think about it intuitively, I just did some calculations. I will put my calculations on my question page.

Comment: For $t \approx \pi$, you have $Re^{it} + R \approx 0$, and $1 + (Re^{it}+R)^4 \approx 1$.

Comment: As long as $R > 2$, isn't it okay?

Comment: oh wait no. sorry

Comment: So the inequality part doesn't work right?

Comment: But shouldn't this be correctable because the exponential part grows much faster than $R$?

Comment: No. In fact, you have $$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{4iz}}{1+z^4}\,dz = - \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-4x}}{1+x^4}\,dx.$$ That much is easy to see. Unfortunately, I don't see an immediate easy way to compute the latter integral.

Comment: Does the residue value get $0$?

Comment: No, note that there's no $i$ in the exponent of the last integral. If $R$ is large enough that the pole in the first quadrant is between $\gamma_R$ and the real axis, the integral over $\gamma_R$ is by Cauchy's integral theorem equal to the integral over $[2R,2R+ 2iR] + [2R+2iR, 2iR] + [2iR,0]$. The integrals over the first two segments vanish in the limit. (And I forgot a factor $i$ before the last integral, just to mention it.)

Comment: Um.. I'm not sure why you say no... I think it's better that we don't have $i$ in there. By $\delta$ above, I still expect the value can be controlled but I may be wrong. Anyway, let me put few more equations (maybe tomorrow, gotta sleep..) that I've done.

And as for your approach, I get the Cauchy part. So the difficult part is on the last segment, I guess?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hey Sorry by the way, I got your meaning of 'the last integral' wrong; I thought you meant the last integral on the question. And by your exposition, now I get why it might not vanish over $[2iR,0]$ and therefore not on the whole arc.

Comment: @DanielFischer And now I see the above delta control does't work.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{4x\ic} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{x}\,{\expo{4x\ic} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pars{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}{\expo{\ic kx} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}}\,
{\expo{4x\ic} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}{1 \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\pars{k + 4}x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}{1 \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}{1 \over k}\,
\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\equiv {\cal I}\pars{k}}}
+
\half\
\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{{\cal I}\pars{0}}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> The zeros of $x^{4} + 1 = 0$ are given by $x_{n} \equiv \expo{n\ic\pi/4}$.
> $n = 1, 3, 5, 7$
> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}\pars{k}&\equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x} \over x^{4} + 1}\,\dd x
> =
> 2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 1,3}\lim_{x \to x_{n}}
> \bracks{\pars{x - x_{n}}\,{\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x} \over x^{4} + 1}} 
> =
> 2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 1,3}{\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x_{n}} \over 4x_{n}^{3}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\,{\pi\ic \over 2}\sum_{n = 1,3}x_{n}\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}x_{n}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\,{\pi\ic \over 2}\braces{%
> {\root{2} \over 2}\pars{1 + \ic}\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}\root{2}\pars{1 + \ic}/2}
> +
> {\root{2} \over 2}\pars{-1 + \ic}\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}\root{2}\pars{-1 + \ic}/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\ic\,{\pi\root{2} \over 4}\,\expo{-\root{2}\verts{k + 4}/2}\braces{%
> \pars{1 + \ic}\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}\root{2}/2}
> -
> \pars{1 - \ic}\expo{-\ic\verts{k + 4}\root{2}/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\ic\,{\pi\root{2} \over 4}\,\expo{-\root{2}\verts{k + 4}/2}
> 2\ic\Im\braces{\pars{1 + \ic}\expo{\ic\verts{k + 4}\root{2}/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {\pi\root{2} \over 2}\,\expo{-\root{2}\verts{k + 4}/2}\bracks{%
> \sin\pars{{\root{2} \over 2}\,\verts{k + 4}}
> +
> \cos\pars{{\root{2} \over 2}\,\verts{k + 4}}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
{\cal I}\pars{k}
&=
{\pi\root{2} \over 2}\bracks{\Im\phi\pars{k} + \Re\phi\pars{k}}\,,\qquad
\phi\pars{k} \equiv \exp\pars{{\root{2} \over 2}\,\pars{-1 + \ic}\verts{k + 4}}
\\[3mm]
{\cal I}\pars{0}
&=
{\pi\root{2} \over 2}\expo{-2\root{2}}\bracks{%
\sin\pars{2\root{2}} + \cos\pars{2\root{2}}}
\end{align}

> By replacing these results in $\pars{1}$, we get:
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{4x\ic} \over 1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x
> &=
> -\ic\,{\root{2} \over 4}\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd k \over k}\bracks{%
> \Im\phi\pars{k} + \Re\phi\pars{k}}
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}+
> {\pi\root{2} \over 4}\expo{-2\root{2}}\bracks{%
> \sin\pars{2\root{2}} + \cos\pars{2\root{2}}}
> \end{align}

Also
\begin{align}
&\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-z\verts{k + 4}} \over k}\,\dd k
\\[3mm]&=\expo{4z}\int_{-\infty}^{-4}{\expo{zk} \over k}\,\dd k
+
\expo{-4z}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{-4}^{-\epsilon}{\expo{-zk} \over k}\,\dd k
+
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}{\expo{-zk} \over k}\,\dd k}
\\[3mm]&=-\expo{4z}\int^{\infty}_{4}{\expo{-zk} \over k}\,\dd k
+
\expo{-4z}\int_{0}^{4}{\expo{-zk} - \expo{zk}\over k}\,\dd k
+
\expo{-4z}\int_{4}^{\infty}{\expo{-zk} \over k}\,\dd k
\\[3mm]&=
-2\sinh\pars{4z}\int_{4}^{\infty}{\expo{-zk} \over k}\,\dd k
-
\expo{-4z}\int_{0}^{4}{\sinh\pars{zk} \over k}\,\dd k
\end{align}
At this point the remaining integrals $\pars{~\mbox{with}\ z = {\root{2} \over 2}\bracks{1 - \ic}~}$ are quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to integrate $\int ln(z) \frac{e^{4iz}}{1+z^4} dz$ with the branch chosen to be from 0 to $\infty$ and the contour closed in the upper half plane. The path integral along the branch should give you what you want.

Comment: $\lvert e^{4iz}\rvert = e^{-4 \operatorname{Im} z}$. The part of the circle in the lower half plane doesn't play nicely.

Comment: Guys do you think the contour $[0,2R] \cup \gamma_R$ with $\gamma_R(t) = Re^{it} + R$ would work?

Comment: what if you just close the contour in the upper plane with the same branch choice?